# Who is at the highest level of command at Ubuntu?

Tags: community

Just like my question asks - who is at the head of Ubuntu and how do I contact them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the CEO's of [Canonical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_Ltd.), from which is would be manageable to contact them if necessary. One has a website providing an email address, another has a twitter feed. For example:

http://www.markshuttleworth.com/contact-details

https://plus.google.com/116812394236590806058/posts

and

http://www.jonobacon.org/contact/